# Java heap size problems with SpringSource tcServer on Cloud Foundry

Tags: jvm, cloud-foundry

I am using Cloud Foundry with tcServer to deploy my java application but am experiencing out-of-memory issues as I cannot seem to get any Java heap settings to take effect. Does anyone have any experience of changing Java heap settings using the Cloud Foundry interface?

I am using a large EC2 instance (64bit) and I have tried the following:

- Entered -Xmx3g in JVM OPtions of the Application definition
- Entered -Xmx3g in the JVM Options of the Deployment definition
- Tried overriding in the setenv.sh script of tcServer on the instance
- Tried overriding in the wrapper.conf settings of the tcServer on the instance

Nothing I try effects the reported max heap size of 1gb from the Cloud Foundry console. Even setting to a lower value has no effect. I can confirm that the JVM on the box is a 64-bit version.

Predictably, as the user volume grows on my service, the system stacks run out of memory.

Does anyone have any similar experience of getting CloudFoundry to accept JVM options, or failing that know how to make tcServer (that is installed by Cloud Foundry without any AMS tools such as tcsdamin as far as I can see) take some new values on restart?

Answer (score 2):

Ok - in case anyone stumbles on this one too, here's my solution:

1. forget what it says in the Cloud Foundry interface as it has no effect
2. forget putting things in setenv.sh as it has no effect
3. Ignore wrapper.conf unless you are on windows
4. **go edit /etc/init.d/tcserver and change the hardcoded -Xmx1G kindly provided by SpringSource**